# html image to pdf (images not showing) - selectpdf

Tags: html, vb.net, pdf, selectpdf

I am creating pdf files from generated html file by using PdfSelect, the problem is that images are not show on the pdf but is generated on the html.

```
  Dim converter As New HtmlToPdf()

        ' set converter options
        converter.Options.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4
        converter.Options.PdfPageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait
        ' create a new pdf document converting an url
        Dim doc As SelectPdf.PdfDocument = converter.ConvertUrl(htmlFilePath)

        ' get image path
        Dim imgFile As String = "C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Acczone General\statements\leda.jpg"



        ' save pdf document
        doc.Save(pdfFilePath)

        ' close pdf document
        doc.Close()
```

I tried some coding but it does not work, can someone please help me so that the images show on the pdf?

My html works 100% it is just the pdf, i am using SelectPdf

Comment: Is `imgFile` supposed to be relevant? You never use the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this format:

```
Dim imgFile As String = "file:///C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Acczone General\statements\leda.jpg"
```